# How Can I get the Highest Value ResultPoint and ResultPercentage

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT DISTINCT
info_person.userUsername,
infoExamResult.resultPoint,
infoExamResult.resultPercentage,
infoExamResult.optAnswer
FROM info_person
INNER JOIN infoExamResult ON infoExamResult.personID = info_person.personID
where infoExamResult.datetimeStart BETWEEN "2024-03-18" AND "2024-03-26"
and infoExamResult.optAnswer = "COMMIT"
ORDER BY info_person.userUsername
```

## Outcome

which resultPoint are Score and resultPercentage are Percent of max score

```
+-------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    userUsername   |    resultPoint   |  ResultPercentage |    optAnswer   |
+-------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    NSO001000      |      20          |       50%         |    COMMIT   |
|    NSO001000      |      10          |       25%         |    COMMIT   |
|    NSO002000      |      40          |       100%        |    COMMIT   |
|    NSO002000      |      30          |       75%         |    COMMIT   |
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

I use Distinct userUsername Already but 1 user has 2 resultPoint I want to get The highest Point
Im really beginner with SQL

And this what i want Look like

## What I Looking for

```
+-------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    userUsername   |    resultPoint   |  ResultPercentage |    optAnswer   |
+-------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    NSO001000      |      20          |       50%         |    COMMIT   |
|    NSO002000      |      40          |       100%        |    COMMIT   |
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Some example of data and required output would be great.

Comment: *I use Distinct userUsername Already* DISTINCT is not a function. It is applied to whole row, not to separate column. If the rows differs in at least one column value then they differs and won't be collapsed to one row.

Comment: Read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), provide #5 and #3.

Comment: I Show some example and what result I want rly don't know how to